# mcvs qwt - must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qwidget, qwt

I would like to ask if you could help me with my app.
I have an application in C++ using Qt (and Qwt) in MCVS 2010. I want to open QDialog window with QwtPlot on button click from Main Window (QMainWindow). Here is some code:

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked                           ()
{
    Dialog_plot dp;
    dp.setModal(true);
    dp.exec();
}
```

**Dialog_plot.cpp:**

```
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_canvas.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include "Dialog_plot.h"

Dialog_plot::Dialog_plot(QWidget *parent)
{
    plot = new QwtPlot();

    //more code...
```

**main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This code is compiling, but when I click on that pushbutton_1 in my application I'm getting error:

```
Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

I know that such error was discussed many times and I was reading a lot about it but I can't see solution for my problem. 
One more thing I would like to mention - I have similar application with Qwt plot written by somebody else and his application compiles and works without any problems in my MCVS. I was trying to compare Linker/libraries included but it seems to be the same. So I guess there is a problem with my application, I just can't solve it. I really need some help!

Comment: change dp.exec() to dp.show(). you are blocking the program flow within dp.exec()

Comment: Thank you, Canberk, but it still doesn't work... Still don't know what to do...

Comment: try to declare `dp` at mainwindow header.. change Dialog_plot dp to dp = new Dialog_plot(). In your code it is cleared after on_pushButton_1_clicked ends (stack memory).

Comment: I have changed some code and now it looks like this: (in MainWindow.h: Dialog_plot *dp;). Then in MainWindow.cpp in contructor: (dp = new Dialog_plot(); ) and in on_pushButton_1_clicked I have only "dp->show();)

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Check parent widgets, make sure QwtPlot's parent is Dialog_plot, Dialog_plot's parent is mainwindow etc. And please debug and see at which line it crashes. Or at least post the whole code. push button calls dialog plot constructor and we have no idea whats going on there.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the solution. It was not about code - it was fine. It was about debug and release mode. I thought, that it was enough to switch from release to debug mode. But it wasn't. I had to check configuration of project and that solved my problem.